# PaymentIntent status Processing

Tags: stripe-payments

Can a card payment cause a PaymentIntent to go into the `processing` status?

And what happens when we `confirm` a PaymentIntent that requires processing? The [docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/confirm) state:

> If payment succeeds, the PaymentIntent will transition to the succeeded status.

Does that mean the `confirm` endpoint waits for the processing? Or does it return an error? Or does it succeed without waiting?

Answer (score 1):

> Can a card payment cause a PaymentIntent to go into the processing status?

No, according to https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-methods

(Second question remains unanswered)